# Decode chunked response on nodeJS Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, chunked

How do you guys read chunked response on nodejs ?
Raw Data :

```html
\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003���W�H�\u0000�s8��\u001f:�������G�\u001d�\u0005B&�$�\u0000��2\\N�j�\n���\u0003�\u0002�����Բe\u001b��;s���,��Q]]]]]U�]z�s;��5\u000b#7�m�a�\r��^����6����n\u001b;��7/�\u001e���~|@�1�?�����>1��گ����۳����g�?\u0011\u0000@�B�Gn\f\u0000�W�\u001d\u001c\u001a�\u0018���U����X7�V\u0010\u000ejg'�[������\u001ak5-'v����\u001b�bϣQd\u001b~P�\u001a\u0011?�\u0005=\u001a3��1\u001bE�`��S<\u00193[5\u0017��lDys�a�$�� \u001eŎ1� �q?�\u000bPk�~�Z`$\u000b��AZ.\u0018��\u0011���\u000f\u0006����/�Ӭ���z�\u0006�U��\u000f\n�u��Μ:[5�+�\u0010�o�y�\u001b��>:�\u0002����-�ƴz\u001d�h7�h8�\u0015Ӣ�n\u000en��X7\b��^0B�۵~WR��\u0012��\t�Ng�ś\u0011�)A\u0000U�g�BÿU��V��ј�n׃��\u0005~���6>\u001c��\u00190�7\f�\u0011�\u001b\u0006�\u0015B�\u0017\u0015�g0�Z����5\u001c�6�\ri\u0018��N�>p'�y\u0013�Bw\u001c\u00131���WzME��)߸�\u0013�X�'\u0007_>�ߗ��}�P�X^@\u001d\u0016^B+}w`�ݎ]�e|��Ï_��~��fw�˻���϶�О\u0007ż����\u0010�\u000f��O�\u001e2p96��W��;\t�����/ٹQ���!\tl|����8\b��u��Ў!��~a����\u0003Kf�)X��sv�\u000eY���Bp�*\u000ff`�\u0015+\u000f2\u0013[R�\u000f��� \u001a��t\u000b�D�GEV���� ,������oy�\u001f��v��V�ޝ\u0007\u0017�\u0014���]�u��\u0018q�.\u000e'w\u0011��\u001f\u0005\u001e[]�\u000f0&\u0003�}�Ѹ7��><�6M׎�\u0006cFŤ��ج�\u0011���P\u0002�\u0003\u0006�N� �\u0003f\rX�\u0001dA����=:���\u0015�=\u0017 �\u0000 m��\n\u001a\u001a���\u0014?�eݬ6^�v`\u0001\u001f��# �î�\n/\u0004OP�2S\u0002��\n��[QLu�\u0007��ɫ��\u0005t2\\`�\u0010�_��a\u0010\u001aٸ\u0003��hV\u0014��U\u0005����j�},��\u0016��Q��Q\u000e���\t������|8$o\u000f~9�tt�\u0019_?\u001f�=\u0000�@\tN�\u00161�h9ʁ\u0005�b�㇊�5p�u�\u0018\u0015��y�pa6\u0017\u000f:���
```

toString('utf8')

```html
���iw�8��9>���=ג��x�#��xK'��v�N/����DHbL�j.�5�����B�%9���~�M��"� �B����܍��'F�V�u}�V;8? ��;���rR?rcH�Z��� �0�ǭZ���ֺ]��pP;?��!�V���X�i9�ctVV��{�"���ꗈ�/�јč�(�cƟ�ɘ٪��7d#ʛ; '���(v������]�Z����#Y��r�`l�X͏~0�� �~!�f�^��5ȯ T~Poz4t��٪�\ф(~�+ܨ�������,�l94�՛�G��G� ���wsp��ǺApm��B߮��� ��p|Lu:+/ތXL ��?���y����4v�O/�c�Ƕ���f΀��a���0H�¾�P=��Ԫ��.�ᘴIoHÈ�v��;̛��㘈��%��*R�N������::=���������J����� Z����n�:-��������ۏ���������~����<(�Օ^��~��~����˱�L�r��IX�7�_~�.���� I`��}���AG����v)�K�G=�X2�L�2U�l\^��v��$���Vy43�Xy��ؒJ|4Ѱm�[�'z?*�����aY4^oo|�c� ���� ��"����<����Ĉ+�q8�����(����|�1@�c�ƽ!v����i�v\63*&���fŌ��m��0�w!0k��� �Ǿ��AdT�h���i�T��X]-���/�f��Ҷ��� vcTx!x����|V�D1չtN&�����p��C�~U�Ahd���YQL{�`:ަ�����^Z�Fe�F9,G�d��ãs����r�����~:>8�@ N�1�h9ʁ�b��Ǌ�%p�u���y�xi6:�����wv���h�0������n�g�G��0>�뱱�R�-ա�+*Ff+��P��?wG�\1_�/uR˩P0����E�coR��nd�2 ��NT��^6�.�C����E�v��`���$�u�!�[�:�\߈��|Q����GA���ӏ6 ��3�Ϛ� RrŅ��.�|��eH}�Kg��5�z�$���m)���k&�ˆ��<�Y}F�l,� g@����vȧa��� N��*I�U� ΄���������b@����G71�@zu5.��Yw����vq����D�^��#Y���,�'Д�f7�/�&X�ӛw��N ��}G�����ꬮ:�:6X�\4�3��p��V���J�l�\�h^�E��e��9�crf�{@��4+vG�f~�,ڛ����O��fq[��+dB�c4�����P|�[cU�0�m����AZ3��"*Y3��n�!q2yڸl�G�(ڽ�o�f��[TKX^-����h ����d��l� ���Q�q+m>�%޲>2/bE�[b �$^]���7/-˸�ʞ;E=]��0@V㴰Y�wlͲ��A��X^`�@�QX�F��]9_e �=[eQF���x�,-�x�$4B�ϡ��Q(��8�ƚk��?��A��<��p�ƪh*q=_ h��� �~Ԩ�m/7�du�U�̔9�#��g�Dx������'�.�ʔ�p�w�Ot�����k�DFfW�@h�� �5H�=�����qu��z^Z �2U}@\����Lo4b�+X#Zs*{�f�8�o t },� ��A�|��9���z�0U)��!��$B���05!�(7l��c>Mf'wt���6���@�4���5uY��90C��>��ЫVRU��VqiƸ�i��m.NAx2�}`Wf�; ��V����,�0~s��?1w�@�7�%��2�����(�$�,�'2|TgI\��1�r��hr]�����l �WG2eR@����{�o�NA���OǨ�ό�8z��� �f-���TfJ��oܒ�gXnBk��Xr9���v�Q�(S;��ڳ���1g���@Cb� ��%�d����t�5a~��Y��O��茔%��G��U�W���9��S{�=k����Y0f��sȃb�9��%����Y�+�E�G�@�z ��CA���0��R �l��a"+*m$��+�F �X�kޣ�����������~��/%��*��8l{��@˩�S�Z�,�81G��.p���6
```

Translating this with toString('utf8') make it more unreadable.

Here is the header,

```html
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
```

Is there any option i can read the chunked data like this. To make it readable for me. I was scraping a website, and the body is displayed like that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It would appear that you have "pure binary data" ...

Comment: Is there any possibility i can translate "Pure binary data"  ? or it needs secret key from the server side ? @MikeRobinson

Comment: **A)** "Pure binary data" means "it is not text", so there is no way to "translate" it unless you know exactly what it represents. **B)** The transfer encoding is a red herring. It should not concern you unless you are implementing an HTTP client library. Which you shouldn't do, and which I assume you are not doing here. You should add more of your code and give some detail about what data you expect to get from the server here.

Comment: I want to scrap a website but the only thing I have is data like this, even the body on_ request(options5,function (error, response5, body) {_ also displayi ng data like this. '�v�8�0�;^k���Kc�%ے9�['�el��i��$Bc�T�bG���y���y��b���$v<����L�E�P(�
@�嫯S۸��o�N�Ш�'

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the response is gzipped; if you add `gzip: true`, the response will likely be human readable again.

From the request docs https://github.com/request/request:

> For backwards-compatibility, response compression is not supported by
>   default. To accept gzip-compressed responses, set the gzip option to
>   true. Note that the body data passed through request is automatically
>   decompressed while the response object is unmodified and will contain
>   compressed data if the server sent a compressed response.

```
var request = require('request')
  request(
    { method: 'GET'
    , uri: 'http://www.google.com'
    , gzip: true
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {
      // body is the decompressed response body
      console.log('server encoded the data as: ' + (response.headers['content-encoding'] || 'identity'))
      console.log('the decoded data is: ' + body)
    }
  ).on('data', function(data) {
    // decompressed data as it is received
    console.log('decoded chunk: ' + data)
  })
  .on('response', function(response) {
    // unmodified http.IncomingMessage object
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      // compressed data as it is received
      console.log('received ' + data.length + ' bytes of compressed data')
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer you are looking for. Works for http2, I bet it does for http as well:

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const zlib = require('zlib');

let zip = zlib.createGunzip();

... client ...
const req = client.request()
req.pipe(zip);

let buffer = [];

zip.on('data', (chunk) => {
  buffer.push(chunk.toString());
});

zip.on('end', () => {
  console.log(buffer.join(''));

  client.close();
});
req.end();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).